# Refers to a node on a chemfig inside a node in a tikzpicture. Macro definitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, expansion, chemfig

Consider the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}                                              

\usepackage{tikz}                                                          
\usepackage{chemfig}                                                       

\begin{document}                                                           

\begin{tikzpicture}                                                        

\path node(A){\chemfig{                                                    
 @{N1}N(-[::90,0.4,,,draw=none]H)-[::-30](<[::-60]CH_2-[::0]OH)-[::60](=[::60]O)-[::-60]-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 @{N2}N(-[::-90,0.4,,,draw=none]H)-[::30](<:[::60]CH_2-[::0]OH)-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-[::60]-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 @{N3}N(-[::90,0.4,,,draw=none]H)-[::-30](<[::-60]CH_2-[::0]OH)-[::60](=[::60]O)-[::-60]-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
}};                                                                        

\end{tikzpicture}                                                          

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]                              
\draw[red,very thick](N1)--(N3);                                           
\end{tikzpicture}                                                          

\end{document}
```

[image: molecules with a red line between 2 atoms]

Is there a way to put all in one tikzpicture and avoid the need to compile twice? And more important: How can I define variables that allow to do something like this??:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\def\sera#1{@{N#1}N(-[::90,0.4,,,draw=none]H)-[::-30](<[::-60]CH_2-[::0]OH)-[::60](=[::60]O)-[::-60]}
\def\serb#1{@{N#1}N(-[::-90,0.4,,,draw=none]H)-[::30](<:[::60]CH_2-[::0]OH)-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-[::60]}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path node(A){\chemfig{
 \sera{1}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 \serb{2}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 \sera{3}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,very thick](N1)--(N3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with let to the error

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named N1 is known
```

I figure out that the error come from the expansion of the variables.... but is not in my understanding yet how this work, and I appreciate any help.

Note: I want to handle different chemfig with tikzpicture, therefore the straightforward way with a standalone \chemfig and then a \chemmove is not convenient for my needs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your second question, you have it basically ok. Just modify these lines as following (treat them as submolecules):

```
\path node(A){\chemfig{
 !{\sera{1}}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 !{\serb{2}}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
 !{\sera{3}}-[,0.3,,,draw=none]
}};
```

Compiling it with pdflatex should do the work.

Comment: Wonderful! The second question was the main one, and this works perfectly. Thank you very much.